# Navigator Pushnamed not found route inside listview.builder in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

I want to create a list of subjects in which it takes me a new widget but all body child pushnamed works fine but it did not find a route inside the listview.builder, I don't know why I tried the push method instead of push named so it works fine but when I press back it removes the current widget also subject list widget and goes back to the main root widget kindly guide me on what I can do I try gesture detector but not work still get the error.

```
     ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return GestureDetector(
              child: Card(
                color: Color(0xff18728a),
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: 4.0, horizontal: 12.0),
                elevation: 4.0,
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    '${listSubject[index]['subject_name']}',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  /*Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => SubjectDetails(
                              subjectId: '${listSubject[index]['id']}',
                            ),
                            maintainState: true,
                          ),
                        );*/
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/subject_details');
                  isLoading = false;
                });
              },
            );
```

rout name :

```
       onGenerateRoute: 
      (RouteSettings settings) {
    print(settings.name);
    if (settings.name == '/') {
      return PageTransition(
          type: PageTransitionType.fade, child: MainScreen());
    } else if (settings.name == '/dashboard') {
      return PageTransition(
          type: PageTransitionType.fade, child: Dashboard());
    } else if (settings.name == '/profile') {
      return PageTransition(
          type: PageTransitionType.fade, child: Profile());
    } else if (settings.name == '/subjects') {
      return PageTransition(
          type: PageTransitionType.fade, child: Subjects());
    } else if (settings.name == '/subject_details') {
      return PageTransition(
          type: PageTransitionType.fade, child: SubjectDetails());
    }else{
      print('no value');
    }

  },
```

Comment: can you show your named routes section

Comment: @VilsadPP i update my question/

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 (implicit) navigators in your sample project. A root one in https://github.com/itsdani121/wsms_user/blob/master/lib/main.dart and a another one in https://github.com/itsdani121/wsms_user/blob/master/lib/Subjects.dart#L39. `Navigator.pushNamed(context,...)` looks for the nearest Navigator which is in Subjects.dart which doesn't define any named routes. Your `Navigator.push(context,...)` example works because any Navigator can take in a new `MaterialPageRoute` so it didn't matter which Navigator was found to be the nearest via the passed in `context`.

Comment: when i use without listview.builder, pushnamed works fine but i use inside builder it did not found route.

Comment: hi @xster can you give answer about this question https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/192570887  i am very thankful to you.